# How to implement Interface in Enums (with parameters) without overriding methods

Tags: java, enums, interface, enumeration

I have Enumutils like below:

```
public interface EnumUtil {
    String getValue();

    static <T extends Enum<T> & EnumUtil> T fromValue(String enumValue, Class<T> type) {
        EnumSet<T> all=EnumSet.allOf(type);
        for (final T t: all) {
            System.out.println("Value: " + t.getValue());
            System.out.println("Name: " + t.name());

            T val = T.valueOf(t.getDeclaringClass(), t.name()).;
            System.out.println("ValValVal: " + val);

            if (t.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(enumValue)) {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I have created an enum which appears as follows:

```
@Getter 
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum SupportedOptions implements EnumUtil {
    PART("PART"),
    MSRV("MSRV");

    private final String value; //If we add this line then we need not to override getValue()

    public static SupportedOptions fromValue(final String text) {
        return EnumUtil.fromValue(text, SupportedOptions.class);
    }
}
```

This works fine without any compilation issues. (getValue also returns the enum parameter successfully in fromvalue in EnumUtils interface for this enum)

But in the following scenario it results in a compile time exception (need to implement abstract methods).

```
@Getter 
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum RejectedResponseCode implements EnumUtil {
    UNPR("300", "849", "700", "701", "702", "703", "705", "730","704"),
    IMSG("302", "105", "113", "114"),
    PARS("107", "100", "102", "103", "115","720"),
    SECU("302", "668", "669", "670", "671");

    //approach 1
    private final String value; //Here it want some value as i am using constructor like below

    RejectedResponseCode(final String... codes) {
        this.codes = Arrays.asList(codes);
        //this.value = getValue(); <--- Is this approach fine. (For appraoch 1)
    }

    private final List<String> codes;

    public static RejectedResponseCode getValueOfData(final String value) {
        final Optional<RejectedResponseCode> result =  Arrays.stream(values()).filter(rejectedResponseCode -> rejectedResponseCode.codes.contains(value)).findFirst();
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            return result.get();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static RejectedResponseCode fromValue(final String text) {
        return EnumUtil.fromValue(text, RejectedResponseCode.class);
    }

    //Approach 2 
    //@Override
    //public String getValue(){
    //  return null; //Is this approach correct?
    //}
}
```

How to ignore either not to override getValue()?
Or how to override getValue() in such a way that it returns parameter
or any other way to manage this in EnumUtil?

Comment: "This works fine without any Compilation issues" how, the `getValue()` method isn't implemented, and the field isn't initialized? https://ideone.com/g7IrSx

Comment: It is working bro and code is exactly same.

Comment: "It is working bro" I have provided a demonstration that it doesn't given the code in the question. Please provide evidence of your claim that it compiles.

Comment: Remember that people can't see your actual code, they can only see the code you put in your post, and _that_ code has compilation errors in this case. Remember to verify that the ([mcve]) code you put in your post reflects your real code.

Comment: @AndyTurner: You are true. Sorry. I missed Lombok things. Just updated code

Comment: Remember also that we are not your peer reviewer. If they are objecting to your code, you should talk to them to understand their objections.

Comment: `EnumUtil.fromValue()` simply assumes that there's always exactly one identifiying string for each enum value. That's not true for your second sample. So either don't use `EnumUtil.fromValue()` or extend it to also support multiple values (probably by having a second interface that can return an array or collection of potentital identifiers)

Comment: @AndyTurner: Now i have updated those annotations of lombok I hope now it may give more picture?

Comment: If you are getting a compiler error, then please include that error in your question.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Accepting your comment as answer of this. Thanks for way. May be you can add it as answer. Will accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search each enum value supporting multiple search keys, so implementing `getValue` is no use. On way around this is to reverse the operation such that the enum supplies a set of search criteria to be used, and implement a simple utility method on EnumUtil:

```
public class EnumUtil {
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T,V> T match(T[] values, V fieldValue, BiPredicate<T,V> ... checks) {
        for (var pred : checks)
            for (T item : values)
                if(pred.test(item, fieldValue))
                    return item;

        return null; // OR throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not found: "+fieldValue);
    }
}
```

Then your enum classes can setup any number of search parameters. SupportedOptions just matches on name:

```
enum SupportedOptions {
    PART,
    MSRV;
    public static SupportedOptions fromValue(final String text) {
        return EnumUtil.match(values(), text.toUpperCase(), (e, s) -> e.name().equals(s));
    }
}
```

RejectedResponseCode matches on `name()` and `codes.indexOf`:

```
enum RejectedResponseCode {
    UNPR("300", "849", "700", "701", "702", "703", "705", "730","704"),
    IMSG("302", "105", "113", "114"),
    PARS("107", "100", "102", "103", "115","720"),
    SECU("302", "668", "669", "670", "671");

    RejectedResponseCode(final String... codes) {
        this.codes = Arrays.asList(codes);
    }
    private final List<String> codes;

    public static RejectedResponseCode fromValue(final String text) {
        return EnumUtil.match(values(), text.toUpperCase(), (e, s) -> e.name().equals(s), (e, s) -> e.codes.indexOf(s) >= 0);
    }
}
```

So, anything can be located by name:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (String s : new String[] { "PART", "msrv", "other"})
        System.out.println("SupportedOptions.fromValue("+s+") => "+ SupportedOptions.fromValue(s));

    for (String s : new String[] { "UNPR", "imsg", "102", "671", "999999"})
        System.out.println("RejectedResponseCode.fromValue("+s+") => "+ RejectedResponseCode.fromValue(s));
}

SupportedOptions.fromValue(PART) => PART
SupportedOptions.fromValue(msrv) => MSRV
SupportedOptions.fromValue(other) => null
RejectedResponseCode.fromValue(UNPR) => UNPR
RejectedResponseCode.fromValue(imsg) => IMSG
RejectedResponseCode.fromValue(102) => PARS
RejectedResponseCode.fromValue(671) => SECU
RejectedResponseCode.fromValue(999999) => null
```

Answer (score 0):

As directed by Joachim Sauer in comment:

EnumUtil.fromValue() simply assumes that there's always exactly one identifiying string for each enum value. That's not true for your second sample. So either don't use EnumUtil.fromValue() or extend it to also support multiple values (probably by having a second interface that can return an array or collection of potentital identifiers) –

Accordingly, EnumUtils Removed from enum and created methods inside enums only.